# bullets missing in IE7

Tags: html, css

The browser is IE7. I have no control over that. It sucks, but it's my world. I have also verified that it happens in FF3.6 as well, but honestly, because of the corporate environment, I don't give a hang to make it work there, so long as it works in IE7.

This HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Top level a
         <ul>
           <li>level 2 a</li>
           <li>level 2 b</li>
           <li>level 2 c</li>
           <li>level 2 d</li>
         </ul>
      <li>
      <li>Top level b
        <ul>
           <li>another level 2 a</li>
           <li>another level 2 b</li>
           <li>another level 2 c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Top level c
         <ul>       
            <li>3 level 2 a</li>
            <li>3 level 2 b</li>
            <li>3 level 2 c</li>
            <li>3 level 2 d</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with this css:

```
body { font: 12pt Verdana black; }
/*yellow div entirely for visibility's sake*/
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
ul {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
li { 
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
div ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
div ul li {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
}
div ul li ul { 
    list-style-type: disc;
}
div ul li ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: list-item;
    width: 100%
}
```

What I expect:
The "top level" items will appear in a row from left to right
Their sublists will appear as a vertical list underneath the respective top level item. The sublists will also have a disc as a bullet before each item.

What I get:
The top level items appear as expected, in a row from left to right
Their appear as vertical lists as expected. However, the bullets are missing.

Is this a hopeless case? or can I beat IE7 into submission with correct code?

Comment: You should indent your HTML, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `<li>`s are floating. You only want to float the top level ones, right? Then apply `float:none` to the deeper ones. And you don't need to change the display type to inline; float will do the trick by itself.

By the way, what is the font name? Verdana Black? Then it's STRONGLY recommended to put quotes around the name.

Comment: oh goodness gracious. Why the heck couldn't I even see the float bit? I feel lame. So glad you pointed that out. and, the black.. that's me in my hurry to make the simplest demo of the problem possible trying to shove the color in with the font declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The float is what is removing the bullet points and the `float: left` in `div ul li` is being inherited by `div ul li ul li`.

The solution?

Add `float: none` to `div ul li ul li`.

Also, you are missing a slash from the "top level a" closing `li`

Comment: good catch on the closeing `li`, though there is a spurious `li` as well that was probably supposed to be the closing tag. Also: you got the right solution, 2 minutes after Mr. Lister, so I gave him the check mark. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Just to up the tree, add BODY:

```
body div ul li ul { list-style-type: disc }
```

Resorting to `!important` usually means to need to re-factor your CSS.

By making your selector *more specific* you can usually override most classes.

See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: body in the selector doesn't change the display.
I agree with !important though. There's no conflicting directive, and there's no ambiguity in this simple document. I prefer to not use !important.

Answer (score 0):

Apply it to the `li` tag.

Comment: `list-style-type` is a list property, not an `li` property. Still, I've tried it any way. no change.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the bullets are out of the viewing space of the list (hidden)
try answeres above if not working additionally try a margin and/or padding from left.

Answer (score 0):

check if the colors of the bullets not matching with the background of it. as they are not selectable its hard to figure that out if you just dont notice this might be the problem.

als inspect your element with firebug or chromes debugger... if nothing set the selector might be wrong. if something set it gets overwritten or the problem sits somewhere deeper inside and loughing